# How I use multiple columns on TCheckListBox?

Tags: delphi, tchecklistbox

I'm using the TcheckListBox control and would like to use a second column on this, but besides the Columns and Header properties, I could not find any source on **inserting** the multicolumn contents...

It can look like a noobie question, but Delphi's help doesn't have any content on this, and my searches (on Google and SO) brought much garbage...

I just need an example.

Comment: @Fabricio, the TChecklistbox has only effectively one column of data, the columns property  is just used to wrap the items to another column.

Comment: I'll follow the Listview path that ulrichb indicated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not possible using a `TCheckListBox`.

But you could use a [`TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListView).

Set the `ViewStyle` property to `vsReport` and `Checkboxes` to `True`.

To create the columns and add the items:

```
procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item1, Item2: TListItem;
begin
  ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'aa';
  ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'bb';

  Item1 := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item1.Caption := 'item1';
  Item1.SubItems.Add('subitem1');

  Item2 := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item2.Caption := 'item2';
  Item2.SubItems.Add('subitem2');
  Item2.Checked := True;
end;
```

Looks like:

[list view with checkboxes http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/4681/clipboard01y.png](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/4681/clipboard01y.png)

Comment: Hmmm... It's a interesting idea. I'll explore this tomorrow.

Answer (score 9):

I could be wrong but I thought the columns were for wrapping rather than for formatting purposes.

eg,

Set the number of columns to 2
Add 3 or 4 items
Resize the box vertically and you'll see the items flow to fill the columns

Comment: Yes but it wraps anyway even if you don't want it to. I resize it vertically and instead of getting a vertical scroll bar which would make sense I get a stupid horizontal scroll bar even though columns is set to 1. A potentially useful component thrown in the bin because of bad design.